# svelte memory management stores

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, svelte-store

My question is how subscribe works in a store. Does it work like a reference? Should upload data be stored in a store or is that bad for performance?

Comment: Questions should be limited to one thing; you can just ask multiple questions.

Comment: Please open a separate question for every question you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data from a store is passed as a reference to subscribers, [but it creates a copy in the store when it is set](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/blob/master/src/runtime/store/index.ts#L68). So, depending on the use case, it might not be the best solution as garbage collection does not run immediately (large files might hit memory limits).

I don't see why you'd load data to be uploaded in memory, you can keep a File reference and [possibly create a resized bitmap if you need a image preview while it's uploading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/createImageBitmap).